# $\sigma$-compact and Hausdorff implies paracompact

Tags: general-topology

To prove paracompactness, are the assumptions insufficient? I seem to have proved the statement in the subject line iteratively (by just choosing finite subcovers for $K_n$ and then intersecting with complement of $K_1 \cup \cdots \cup K_{n-1}$). However, it seems typically "LCH" is the assumption, not just Hausdorff, and I do not see the necessity of the additional assumption.

Comment: All $\sigma$-compact spaces are Lindelöf, so any Hausdorff $\sigma$-compact space which is regular is paracompact.

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with the question

Comment: A $\sigma$-compact Hausdorff space is paracompact if and only if it is regular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is untrue. https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/?q=%24%5Csigma%24-compact%2B%24T_2%24%2B%7EParacompact

If you strengthen $\sigma$-compact to "exhaustible by compacts" then you can obtain the result. https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000427/

As you note, adding a compact neighborhood at each point is sufficient to strengthen $\sigma$-compact to exhaustible by compacts. https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000053/

As for your proof, are you assuming each point of the space has some $K_n$ as a neighborhood?

---

On the other hand, your proof does show that every Hausdorff (in fact, any space where compacts are closed) $\sigma$-compact space is *metacompact*. https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000031/

Comment: I do not assume that each point has $K_n$ as a neighborhood. $T_2$ is enough to to conclude each $K_n$ is closed. That seems to be sufficient to say each time you find a finite open cover of a $K_n$ and then intersect with complement of $K_1 \cup \cdots \cup K_{n-1}$, you find a subset of a refinement covering $K_n$. Therefore, I am not quite following what is wrong with my proof.

Comment: I got it! I confused point-finiteness with local finiteness - they are not the same. Thank you Steven.